# Where can i find a list of "Microsoft OS Descriptors" for USB?

Tags: windows, usb, driver

I am trying to find a list of "Microsoft OS Descriptors" for USB.

The best I could do is find a reference to "Appendix 1 of Extended Compat ID OS Feature Descriptor Specification". Of course I can not find this either.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you looking for in particular?  Are you trying to interoperate with a particular set of Windows features/drivers?

Comment: I hate having to sign and supply an installation program to deploy USB inf files for my devices that just use generic bulk pipes. I was just seeing if I can use OS descriptors for that purpose.

Comment: Perhaps SourceUSB may help? http://www.sourcequest.com/modsContent.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you might find this useful:

[Appendix 1 of Extended Compat ID OS Feature Descriptor Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/connect/usb/os_desc.mspx)

Comment: Was there anything interesting in the .exe it lets you download? I ran it but nothing happened.

Comment: It had documentation docs, some examples, but no list of descriptors used by Microsoft.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't of been of any more help.